# Understanding Exception Handling

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I am writing c#. 
Exceptions can be in many other languages
I don't understand how works exception handling, how "try/catch".
I know that error in "try block" go to "catch block". "Catch" can catch different situation how:

1. all errors
2. ArithmeticException
3. DivideByZeroExeption
4. other exeption

Some exeptions I can find in MSDN, some can be common, like arithmetic exception.

But how can I be sure that method has these exceptions? I want to understand this question.
For example in various frameworks, I see method name, but not see method itself.

Comment: In java you have to specify the exceptions a function throws. In c#, or that you don't care, or that it's mentioned in the documentation. All exceptions must inherent from `Exception`.

Comment: These are exceptions you should not catch.  A DivideByZeroException is a bug in your code, you forgot to validate the data.  You cannot handle a bug with code, a programmer is required to fix the bug.  Treat exceptions for what they are, exceptional cases that your program cannot deal with.  You only catch them to tell the user that you are sorry about it.  With AppDomain.UnhandledException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how i can be sure that method has these exceptions?

You can read documentation of that method.You will see a section named `Exceptions`,that list contains exceptions that method can possibly throw.For example take a look at the `int.Parse` method [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you will see these exceptions in Exception list:

1. **ArgumentNullException**
2. **FormatException**
3. **OverflowException**

Comment: Not at my dev box currently, but I think Intellisense tells you the exception types as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can look on MSDN, when you lookup a function/method at the end of the page there's always the list of exceptions that can occur using this function/method. Then if you want to know why these can occur, just click on the exceptions and they will explain on an other web page.